# Permission for event log used in SSRS custom extension

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, extension-methods, ssrs-2008-r2

we are have written one custom input language translator SSRS extension which gets input and convert it into another language and send back. In this extension we have written a code to write error messages using event logger.  When we running our SSRS reports they are showing message error!. But we are not getting any error in event logger only in SSRS trace log it returns "Data not found at parameter 5".

Following is sample asp.net code. Please do let us know permissions needed on extension so that we can write event log.  We are getting error at *Eventlog.SourceExists* in below code.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLogPermission pEventLog = new EventLogPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
pEventLog.Assert();
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Report Server"))
{
  myLog = new EventLog();
  myLog.Source = "Report Server";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, you will not be able to acquire `EventLogPermission` unless the process is running with Administrator permissions.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermission(v=vs.110).aspx

This sounds pretty risky to me.  You might want to use a different logging mechanism (like Log4Net, etc).